# Dual boot Win 10/Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot

is it safe to install Ubuntu after win 10? will I be able to dual boot?
I tried with win 8.1 and ended up with just Ubuntu no Windows

Comment: If  you share a little more details of the machine you're using, it'll be easier to help !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: System Manufacturer: LENOVO
System Model: 20236
BIOS: InsydeH2O Version 03.72.2778CN25WW(V2.03)
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3110M CPU @ 2.40GHz (4 CPUs), .4GHz
Memory: 4096MB RAM

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe to multi-boot your system.
Just turn off the secure boot from BIOS settings.

Do follow the steps of installations of other operating system carefully.